# Rococo can't warp sync - stuck at 16Mb finality proof download

Tags: rococo, sync, warp

I had some trouble recently syncing Rococo from scratch (forcing OOM on servers) so I wanted to use warp sync as a workaround.
But on different servers and on local machine, finality proofs download stays stuck at 15.98 Mib and never gets to download more.

```
2023-08-24 10:14:43 ⏩ Warping, Downloading finality proofs, 15.98 Mib (10 peers), best: #0 (0x6408…063e), finalized #0 (0x6408…063e), ⬇ 3.4MiB/s ⬆ 86.5kiB/s
2023-08-24 10:14:54 ⏩ Warping, Downloading finality proofs, 15.98 Mib (9 peers), best: #0 (0x6408…063e), finalized #0 (0x6408…063e), ⬇ 3.1MiB/s ⬆ 39.6kiB/s
...
2023-08-24 10:49:31 ⏩ Warping, Downloading finality proofs, 15.98 Mib (1 peers), best: #0 (0x6408…063e), finalized #0 (0x6408…063e), ⬇ 278.5kiB/s ⬆ 17.7kiB/s
2023-08-24 10:50:21 ⏩ Warping, Downloading finality proofs, 15.98 Mib (1 peers), best: #0 (0x6408…063e), finalized #0 (0x6408…063e), ⬇ 1.2MiB/s ⬆ 2.3kiB/s
```

Anyone experienced the same or having a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rococo and Westend can both not be warp synced. This is due to a consensus problem that happened and was resolved by sending a root transaction to un-stall the networks. That makes both un-warp able.
There could be improvements to the warp sync to work with checkpoints, but with the current logic its not possible.

Note: We should probably emit an error in the node instead of attempting to warp.

Comment: Thanks for the anszer, I won't insist on warp sync then :)
Btw are you aware of OOM problems triggered by Rococo full sync (non warp mode).
2 nodes of mine are going OOM after some point in sync, with 32Gb RAM it seems very abnormal.

Comment: I think there is an issue for it but cant find it right now. Can you open a new one here please https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues and describe what you did?

Comment: Sure I will as soon as resync gets stuck thanks

Comment: Issue created here
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/1148